# Medal of Honor Open Beta: do accounts carry over?

Tags: medal-of-honor

The [open beta](http://www.medalofhonor.com/pcopenbeta) for the new Medal of Honor title is currently going on, prior to its release on October 12th.  Does anyone know if ranks and customization will carry over via your EA account from the beta to the retail launch?

I would suspect no, but couldn't find any source saying as much.

Comment: Ranks never carry over, that would be unfair.  Can't say about customization, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some searching. I can't find any official EA person saying no, but I have seen a lot of other people saying it([here's one where he mentions ranks too](http://forum.ea.com/eaforum/posts/list/939224.page)) and no one saying yes or even maybe, so I'd highly doubt it since you don't in most betas anyway. =/

Comment: Yeah, this is what I thought, although calling it a beta ending 5 days before launch, isn't it really a glorified demo?  Either way, your point is valid though  :)

Comment: Then are you going to accept it?